# Can't set state in a React functional component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I'm new to React and functional components and I wanted to create a simple app in which I have a `Gallery` component that I'm showing in the app, then I have a button that is supposed to set the state and pass it to the component, this is how it looks:

```
const App = () => {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  return (
    <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.body}>
            <Button title="Press me" onPress={start} />
            <Gallery imgs={images}/> // Using the state here
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

const start = () => {
  // Create images array here
  setImages(images); // [ReferenceError: Can't find variable: setImages]
};

export default App;
```

But I'm getting the following error: [ReferenceError: Can't find variable: setImages], but the setImages variable is defined in the same file so I don't understand what could be the problem.

Not sure if it matters but I'm using TypeScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The state is maintained (declared, set, and used) inside the component.  The function which uses the state also needs to be inside the component:

```
const App = () => {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  const start = () => {
    // Create images array here
    setImages(images);
  };

  return (
    <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.body}>
            <Button title="Press me" onPress={start} />
            <Gallery imgs={images}/> // Using the state here
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Basically, if a variable is declared inside of a function, its scope is limited to only within that function.

Answer (score 1):

David's answer is correct, but if the function needs to be outside the component you can pass all the variables you need as arguments, for example

```js
const App = () => {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  return (
    <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.body}>
            <Button title="Press me" onPress={() => start(setImages)} />
            <Gallery imgs={images}/> // Using the state here
        </View>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

const start = (setImages) => {
  // Create images array here
  setImages(images);
};

export default App;
```